# Pythonic Profiling

Tags: python, anaconda

I have been trying to follow this profiling tutorial:

http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling.html

However, I am on Anacondas / Python 3.3, and the line_profiler is not part of my build. When I try:

```
conda install -n py33 line-profiler
```

I find that the line profiler is not part of Anacondas, which leaves me to ask the question of whether or not there is a more recommendable / Pythonic way of doing profiling in Python?

All I want to do is run %lprun.

Comment: There is a newer version of line_profiler that works with Python 3 but it looks like there isn't a conda package for it. Maybe you can find one at binstar.org.

Comment: Also check out `pyinstrument` (`conda install -c asmeurer pyinstrument`). I like it a lot better than line-profiler for many tasks.